# unresolved assembly reference not allowed: System.Web.Http using ilmerge

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, ilmerge

I'm trying to merge two dll files of my visual studio 2017 project and using the below command line and tried everything but nothing worked out in merging them.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Here are my assemblies installed on my machine:

[image]

[image]

This is the path of the ILMerge where it has been installed

[image]

**IlMerge.exe.config file**:

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <requiredRuntime safemode="true" imageVersion="v4.0.30319" version="v4.0.30319"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

When running using command line getting the below exception:

**Command-line usage:**

```
LMerge.exe /targetplatform:4.0,"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319" /out:C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\XXX\client.dll C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\XXX\lib1.dll C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\XXX\lib2.dll
```

**Exception:**

```
An exception occurred during merging:
Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: System.Web.Http.
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetAssemblyRefIndex(AssemblyNode assembly)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetTypeRefIndex(TypeNode type)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitClass(Class Class)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitModule(Module module)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.SetupMetadataWriter(String debugSymbolsLocation)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.WritePE(Module module, String debugSymbolsLocation,
BinaryWriter writer)
   at System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(String location, Boolean writeDebugSymbols,
 Module module, Boolean delaySign, String keyFileName, String keyName)
   at System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(CompilerParameters compilerParameters, Modu
le module)
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: @downvoter- Care to comment before downvoting.

Is something you didn't understand what I wrote above or something else.. Let me know I'll try to improve it

Comment: ILMerge is now open source at GitHub, so such questions should go there directly, https://github.com/Microsoft/ILMerge It has been a tool not updated for a long time, and patching progress after open sourcing is also not fast. So if you do want to merge something, ILRepack is a better alternative.

Comment: @LexLi- The same error still exists even after using ILRepack

Comment: https://github.com/gluck/il-repack/issues/122

Comment: I got this error when building a multi-project solution in VS and some projects used the "same" DLL. I guess VS uses ILMerge to merge assemblies when it finds that multiple projects need the same reference. For my particular case, the error seems to have been caused by some DLLs maybe not matching in some way. Removing the reference and making sure to re-add the exact same DLL for the corresponding projects looks to have resolves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try There is an easy solution. You simply need to add /targetplatform:v4,[dotnet-path] parameter to your ILMerge build command. For me the framework path is:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
Tyhe full merge command should look something like this:

ilmerge /targetplatform:v4,"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" /out:"c.exe" "a.exe" "b.dll"
This should resolve the issue.

Try running each command with administrative rights fixed mine.

Comment: Is this is not what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is because you are trying to merge a system file to the ILMerge build and that won't work. You need to go the properties tab of the .dll in this case 'System.Web.Http' and set the 'Copy Local' value to False. Hence, this would not copy or try to build the .dll file along with the ILMerge. You can find all your .dll files in the references section in solution explorer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).